# How to make Server bootable CD?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell-poweredge, ms-dos

I need to upgrade firmware in two RAID controllers on my Dell PowerEdge 1950 server running Win2008 64bit, this is required to be done from DOS because the driver gives me an error " You cannot install drivers on 64bit OS".
My question is how to create bootable media, CD would be better in order to install those drivers. In older Windows version there was an option to create a boot diskette but i need this on CD which will load after restart instead of OS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/), maybe this will help you.

Comment: yep something like that ...

Comment: this is not the way with Dell, or any other brandname servers - there are native ways of performing updates, specifically built for these machines

Comment: +1 @dyasny for native methods. I've not seen a firmware update from Dell that isn't designed to run within Windows. Avoid UBCD like mad for jobs like this. Nothing wrong with @SvenW's answer, but I think @eugeneK has asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 2):

DOS no longer exists in Windows, cmd.exe is a Windows program that acts as a DOS-like command line interpreter. You can boot to safe mode with command prompt, that will just give you a command prompt, but that really gives you no extra functionality over doing so in windows.

My first thought would be to see if the manufacturer does have a 64bit version of their firmware upgrade utility. More and more servers are running 64bit OS's nowadays particularly when server 2008 r2 and Exchange are now 64bit only. If they are a reputable RAID controller producer they really should have this available.

If thats a no go, then you have a  few options:

- Download the desired boot disk from [Bootdisk.com](http://www.bootdisk.com/bootdisk.htm)
- Use an boot CD like the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) or [Bart PE](http://www.nu2.nu/bootcd/)
- If there is a Linux firmware updater available, use a Linux Live CD

Answer (score 2):

I am PRETTY sure you'll find the correct way to update your drivers if you investigate a bit more on the Dell website. Maybe you just downloaded the wrong type of the driver or something. Dell is a company that goes to geat lenghts to ensure an optimal administration of their systems, and in my experience deliver very good readmes and manuals that outline the process. Read a bit before you do anything.

Comment: I won't because i already did a mistake that haven't installed Windows using Dell Live CD which automatically installs drivers i've needed and ability to upgrade those. My bad ...

Comment: Just read instructions and i have to do it via bootable media

Comment: I can't see how that can matter too much. F.ex, if its the firmware for the PERC 4e/DC, click "more download options" and you'll see a lot of different options. I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just saying look thoroghly into it first. 

If you really need a bootable CD as simple as possibly running a 32-bit windows OS, I'd just grab a WIndows XP CD, and run it through BartPE (http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) to build a bootable maintenance CD from it. Or use WAIK (free from microsoft.com) to generate a x86 WinPE image.

Comment: God, why do they hide other options... thanks mate, updated via Windows

Answer (score 0):

Dell has a liveCD of their own. Call the server support and ask for a link to download it. The liveCD (at least when I used to work there) is a CentOS live build, meaning you can download the RHEL based firmware update packages, and run the updater on top if the liveCD natively.

Another thing to consider - install OMSA and use IT Assistant (again, for the links to the stuff, and to the mauals - call suport), to upgrade your server remotely.